# Button Onclick only working on first element

Tags: javascript, onclick

When clicking button on elements, overlay box only works with first one, not the rest

I tried already to add 2 classes but not working as I read that that might be the issue, but I am not able to make it work properly.

```
<div class="container">
<input type="button" value="Contactar ahora" id="Overly" class="overly"  
/> 
</div>

<div id="ogrooModel" class="modalbox ogroobox" >
<div class="dialog">
<button  title="Close" onClick="overlay()"  class="closebutton" id="close">close</button>
<div  style="min-height: 150px;">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
//only javascript
document.getElementById("Overly").addEventListener("click", function(){
var e =document.getElementsByClassName("modalbox");

    e[0].style.display = 'block';

})  ;
document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function(){
var e =document.getElementsByClassName("modalbox");
e[0].style.display= 'none';
});
</script>
```

What exactly to change in that code so the rest of elements display the box after clicking on button?

Comment: Can you post the full html code?

Comment: It is the same code, I add the div class container to each element (there are 10 elements). I don't know how to implement two classes here, in case that is what is needed so all the elements display the overlay on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **onClick="overlay()"** for your close button, as you are already binding it with a click event listener in your script.

Comment: So this is the reason why this is only working on first element?